# NativeScript - What is the difference between viewModel.foo and viewModel.get("foo")?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, nativescript, viewmodel

Take the following simplified viewModel:

```
const observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
    const viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
        foo: 'Hello World'
    });

    return viewModel;
}
```

In NativeScript, it's possible to get a viewModel value in two ways:

`viewModel.foo` and `viewModel.get("foo")`

In which case should I use the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are actually same when creating an Observable using `fromObject` method.

`viewModel.foo` will internally be mapped to `viewModel.get("foo")` / `viewModel.set("foo", value)` using `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: So that means, I don't have to use `viewModel.set("foo", value)` either? I could just use `viewModel.foo = value`? (I never dared to do so, lol xD)